# Why the compiler in C++ execute a command before another?

Tags: c++, compilation

could anyone please explain why when i write this code

```
    int x = 6;
    cout << x << endl << ++x << endl;
```

the output is 
7
7

instead of

6
7

sorry i'm a beginner in this language , when i moved from VB.Net to C++ i feel it's more complicated ..

Comment: My feeling is that, occasionally, these types of questions are worth answering. It's a more subtle variant of the ++i + i++ sort of thing.

Comment: Since the dupe doesn't have a c++ tag you might also be interested in reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: I don't really like that dupe since this one has overloaded operators.

Comment: The dupe is inappropriate. It talks about undefined behaviour examples, but there is no undefined behaviour in this question - only implementation defined order of evaluation. Had it been `x << x++ <<endl` that would be undefined, but not with pre-increment used like here

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << x << endl << ++x << endl;
```

translates to

```
cout.operator<<(x).operator<<(endl).operator<<(++x).operator<<(endl);
```

(where each `operator<<` call returns a reference to cout for precisely this call chaining), and this is essentially the same as

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, x), endl), ++x)
```

(with the last/outermost call discarded for clarity, and the member function call rewritten as an equivalent free function).

Ignoring the `endl` (which doesn't touch `x`), the critical part is just a function call of the form

```
struct C;
C& f(C&, int);
...
f(f(c, x), ++x)
```

and, like any other function call, the order in which its arguments are evaluated is not defined.  That is, the compiler can emit

```
int a = f(c, x);
int b = ++x;
f(a, b);
```

**or**

```
int b = ++x;
int a = f(c, x);
f(a, b);
```

There are good reasons for leaving this evaluation order *unspecified* (not undefined): different platforms have different calling conventions, and it gives the optimiser more room to manoeuvre.

Still, if *you* care about the order in which they're evaluated, *you* have to make it explicit.

Comment: Upvoted. I *think* this answer is correct, unlike mine which I've deleted.

Comment: Cheers! The fine details of what goes wrong and why can be tricky, but fortunately they're not required to see that the original code is just _nasty_.

Comment: @Useless AFAIK, `cout << x << endl << ++x << endl;` is unspecified from C++17, it's not undefined anymore

Comment: I think that's what I said, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In a c++ expression, evaluation order of sub-expressions is not specified by the standard and is left as implementation-defined. Thus in your expression your expectation that the `x` part is evaluated before the `++x` part is unfounded: the standard makes no such requirement. In your case the `++x` sub-expression is evaluated first, resulting in 7 being passed as the parameter value in both cases of the `operator<<` invocation. It could just as easily have been the other way round, leading to your expected output: both are correct from the standard's point of view.

Comment: C++ becomes a really great language - nobody knows what is correct and what is not.

Comment: Order of evaluation vs undefined behaviour is particularly notorious for this. I have seen questions again and again in which contradictory answers are given by really quite knowledgeable people

Comment: If you required to be a language lawyer just to realize if expression is valid or not then language has bad problems. I am afraid language writers disconnect with reality more and more. :(

Comment: But you're not required to be a language lawyer to know that this example _just looks suspicious_. It takes some experience, but you don't need to recall the details to know it smells bad.